# .htaccess error 500 happening on one domain but not another

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1
```

This is supposed to rewrite ?p=

http://kush-joint.com/uTsSkf = SERVER 500

http://kush-joint.com/?p=uTsSkf = works

Based on this .htaccess it should work without the ?p= I have this running on many other domians and it works fine but on this clients domain it is not working.

The client has wordpress running on another domain on same hosting account with permalinks so modrewrite is enabled on the account.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Could you post the full .htaccess as well as any relevant messages from the apache error_log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's kind of weird, but without the rewrite log turned on, it's hard to track down what's causing the error. If it's not mod_rewrite not being turned and not some other syntax problem, it's probably something causing a loop.

Some things you can try:

1. include an exclusion for index.php:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1
   ```
2. Add a base:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1
   ```
3. Add a [L] flag (this matters if you have other rules)

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
   ```

Comment: Thanks man your awesome! #2 did the trick the server needed the base rewrite /